# How to decode Gzip Compressed string from .net Webservice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gzip, decode

I got compressed response string from the .net web service in XML format. How to decode the response string?

My code is shown below.

```
NSString *mysUrl=@"myurl";
NSString *soapMsg1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"

                      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"

                      "<soap:Body>\n"
                      "<CompressString xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                      "<text>%@</text>"
                      "</CompressString>"
                      "</soap:Body>\n"
                      "</soap:Envelope>",@"abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz"];



NSLog(@"%@",soapMsg1);



NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:mysUrl];


NSMutableURLRequest *req1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];

NSString *msgLength1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg1 length]];

[req1 addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSLog(@"lenght of the message is.......%@",msgLength1);

[req1 addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/CompressString" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];



[req1 addValue:msgLength1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


  NSLog(@"lenght of the message is.......%@",req1);


[req1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[req1 setHTTPBody: [soapMsg1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;

NSError *error;

//getting the data

[req1 addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];


NSData *newData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"\n\n\n Compression string response %@ \n\n\n",responseString);
```

Comment: What is the question? How is your code failing? Have you de-ziped the data or is that the problem? You really need to put some time into your question if you expect help. Cleaning up the formatting also makes it easier.

Comment: I am using Base64 to deZip the string but it gives null value

Comment: Base64 and zip are two entirely different things. Base64 is binary to ASCII encoding and zip is compression. You still have not stated the problem that you need help with.

Comment: I have following result GgAAAB+LCAAAAAAABABLTEpOSU1Lz8jMys7Jzc8rKCwqLiktK6+orAIAV8UUChoAAAA= for the input string @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".how to get oringinal string.i am new to iphone.please tell methe step to get original string

Comment: What makes you thing that? What code created the output string? I does seem to be legal Base64 but the result is basically binary: 1a000000 1f8b0800 00000000 04004b4c 4a4e494d 4bcfc8cc cacec9cd cf2b282c 2a2e292d 2bafa8ac 020057c5 140a1a00 0000

Comment: I need to send text to above service method and i need to get same string from service response using Gzip method